# Why circles build by CircleType need two reload to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, circletype

### CircleType issue.

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to make a circle with the CircleType library but it doesn't work on the first page load. In order for the circle work and take the desired size I need to reload my page twice (see images). I have already tried changing the radius, font size, script order... If anyone knows how to solve it or has an idea I'd love to hear it.

[image: bug]

After **two refresh**

[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/circletype.min.js">

 <script type="text/javascript">
        const circleType = new CircleType(
            document.getElementById("rotated")
        );
    
    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
            offset = offset * 0.4;
    
            $(".circular-text").css({
                "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
                "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
                "-o-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
                "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
                transform: "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cercle() {
        const circleType = new CircleType(
            document.getElementById("rotated"));
        

    }
    
    $( window ).on( "load", cercle);

    // $(window).scroll(function() {
    //     var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    //     offset = offset * 0.4;

    //     $(".circular-text").css({
    //         "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
    //         "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
    //         "-o-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
    //         "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
    //         transform: "rotate(" + offset + "deg)",
    //     });
    // });
</script>
```

The result at the first load

[image]

Second Load
[image]

Code HTML CSS JS

https://codepen.io/adrian-jamet/pen/mdMBMZE

Comment: Try to wrap your code in `$( document ).ready()` or `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` construction to launch it in the right moment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me @GlebKemarsky.I have just tried your proposal here is an extract of the code to check if I have done things correctly. `<script type="text/javascript">
    function cercle() {
        const circleType = new CircleType(
            document.getElementById("rotated")
        );
    }
    $( document ).ready( cercle );`

Comment: @GlebKemarsky I've tried with $( window ).on( "load",cercle{...};  However, when I use the latter, the circle is no longer packed, but is large with the letters spaced out

Comment: Can you add your HTML to create a snippet that we can run and see the problem?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky  impossible to create a snippet in stackoverflow because it does not interpret the code of the CircleType library. Nevertheless I tried on code pen and I haven't the issue... Is it possible that I am only experiencing the problem locally?

Comment: It will be enough to show a part of your HTML/CSS/JS and load a library from CDN: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/circletype You can type here a code and publish the working example on CodePen, JSFiddle or your own website. Currently we have to guess, instead of trying the situation in action. And this makes it less likely that your question will be answered.